# Starting Activity on back pressed

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app where i show some notifications. After user click on it, some `Activity`, let's call it `Activity B`, is started. After the user press back button, the app is closed but what i want to do is not to close an app but to send it to `Activity A`, which is app `MainActivity` and is started first when app is opened in normal way. If application is started not form push notification, and MainActivity is started as first it works well. I tried to use `android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"` in my manifest for this `Activity B` but it has no effect.

Is there any way to handle it smart or I just have to start the `MainActivity`?

Comment: See my answer it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use like :

```
public void onBackPressed()  
{  
  if(isTaskRoot()){
    this.startActivity(new Intent(BActivity.this,AActivity.class));  
    }
  finish()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to override onBackPressed() and start MainActivity inside it as below

```
 public void onBackPressed() {

 startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should build an intent with a back stack while opening your notification.
Your case is well documented in the Android docs and you can find what you need [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)

The **Regular activity** is your case:

> This is an activity that exists as a part of your app's normal UX flow. So when the user arrives in the activity from the notification, the new task should include a complete back stack, allowing them to press Back and navigate up the app hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Pietro Scarampella's answer i found what i wanted.

`val resultPendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).apply {
            addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
        }.getPendingIntent(messageId, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)`

`intent` here is intent of an Activity i want to start, then i pass my `resultPendingIntent` to my notification with

`NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            [...]
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)`

Also i added to my activity in Manifest

`android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"`

Now, when i click on my notification my desired Activity is started, and when I press back button `MainActivity` is started.

Thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed method in BActivity like this way:

```
public void onBackPressed()  
{  
    this.startActivity(new Intent(BActivity.this,AActivity.class));  

    return;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow in your Activity

Java way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
   myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
   CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Kotlin way:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   val myIntent: Intent = Intent(applicationContext, NextActivity::class.java);
   myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
   startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPress in your activity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    val intent = Intent(applicationContext,Activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called `Up Navigation`.

It's the action that should also be invoked when pressing `Back` button on a `Toolbar` (or `ActionBar`) if the `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` is enabled. For that you should declare an appropriate parent activity for every activity in the app via manifest (except the main one).

In you case you can implement up navigation when `onBackPressed` is called by using `NavUtils` like this:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not calling the `finish();` after you have passed the intent from MainActivity to Activity B.

You can simply use the following code to start an intent from MainActivity to Activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

You can also use `startActivityForResult();` if in case you are looking to send some data back to MainActivity from Activity B.

You can refer to this link for Android Intents for more detail about it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent